# Why is setup.py failing when I try to register with pypi?

Tags: python, markdown, setuptools, restructuredtext, pypi

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my latest project registered with PyPI, and I'm hoping one of you guys can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

My directory is structured as follows:

```
Scrappy/
|-- README.md
|-- setup.py
|-- manifest.in
|-- scrappy
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- core.py
|   |-- formatters.py
|   |-- docopty.py
|   |-- gui.py
|   |-- scrappy.py
|   |-- scrappy.conf
```

My `manifest.in` file is structured as follows:

```
include README.md
include scrappy/scrappy.conf
```

and my setup.py file is structured as follows:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Scrappy',
    version='0.2.1 alpha',
    author='Blz McBlz',
    author_email='xxxx@xxxx.com',
    packages=['scrappy'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=['guessit', 'tvdb_api', 'ez_setup', 'titlecase', 'hachoir-metadata'],
    url='https://github.com/louist87/scrappy',
    license='GPL 3.0',
    description='Rename video files based on information scraped from thetvdb.com',
    keywords=["TVDB", "thetvdb", "rename", "broadcatching", "media"],
    long_description=open('README.md').read()
)
```

A full traceback can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1490510/)

I tried loading `README.md` in a python shell via `lines = open('README.md').read()`.  No error was raised and the text was indeed in the `lines` variable as expected.

**EDIT:** [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1492206/) is the `README.md` file in question.

Comment: Even though it is very long, it is still preferred to include the full traceback in your question text.

Comment: the line mentioned in the traceback is not neccesarily to blame; it will normally be the last line of a multiline statement, which in this case is the function call to `setuptools.setup()`.   On the other hand, it looks like its dying on some restructured text processing;  are you using restructured text in your documentation?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy, I'm afraid I don't know what restructured text is.  I'm adding a link to the `README.md` file... maybe you can tell me if I'm using restructured text? =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that setuptools requires reStructuredText and not markdown syntax in the long_description field.

Comment: [Here is](https://coderwall.com/p/qawuyq) a recipe on using markdown in pypi packages.